# Will an application compiled for iOS 3 run on iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios

I compiled an application for iOS 3, Will it run on iOS 4? Or do I send 2nd version of the application to App Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will run, but won't take advantage of the new stuff in iOS4. Otherwise, lots of apps currently in the AppStore that haven't been updated wouldn't work on the new iPhones.

Comment: Thank you. I was suspecting that but wanted to find out for sure. Could it work the other way around as well if the application isn't implementing anything specific for iOS 4?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think so, since I've had apps built for the compass on the 3GS working on my 3G. That was more a hardware limitation though, but I'd think it would be handled similarly.

Comment: For the first comment: An application compiled for iOS 4.0 will run on iOS 3.0 as long as you set your base SDK to 4.0 and the deployment target to 3.0

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter any more.  Apple is [currently only accepting applications and updates built against iOS 4.0 for the App Store](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/news/archives/2010/june/):

> Make sure that your applications are
>   compatible with iOS 4. All new
>   applications and updates to existing
>   applications must be built with iPhone
>   SDK 4. In addition, the App Store will
>   no longer support applications that
>   target iOS 2.x.

It's my understanding that a 3.x-only application will now be rejected.  However, it is trivial to ensure that your 4.0-built application will run on 3.x devices by setting the Deployment Target to 3.0 (or later).